# PC shuts down automatically while playing videos

Tags: windows-vista, shutdown

I'm using a Windows Vista PC. Whenever I play videos for more than 15 mins, my PC will automatically shut down.

What could the problem be? Any ideas how to stop it shutting down?

Comment: Should this go on Super User?

Comment: ya...Is this the virus problem or any settings problem?.

Comment: could be cpu overheating. Intel cpus will force shutdown if temp. gets to high.

Comment: It happened to me with my older laptop. When I played flv inside browser cpu usage was high, it heated up and shutdown ! Keep you task manager on and check the cpu usage while video is playing.